# Removing left and right Structural Block on one Page

Tags: layout, blocks

i'm trying to remove left and right blocks for one page, basically making it into 1 column page. But the page i'm making is not through the cms. Forex: it's from Company_Demo page with my own xml and phtml file (making a page through code). I've override the `content` block at my xml but i've got no idea to make the page into 1 column page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your layout file add below code:

```
 <remove name="right"/>
 <remove name="left"/>
```

As an example if you want to remove left and right sidebar for category listing

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
```